# How to add ReactJS /build folder to an existing website structure

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, reactjs, create-react-app

I have already built my Create React App and compiled it to a `/build` folder. I also have a website (on WordPress in particular) where I am hoping to add my app.

My problem is that I can only find documentation on how to publish the app as a single page HTML document utilizing the `index.html` file. I want to somehow include only the part between the app's `<body>` if possible.

What happens when I have a preexisting `<div id="root"></div>` element inside my plugin? I have already added the `/build` folder in plugins root as well.

The produced code is

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <title>React App</title>
  <link href="/static/css/main.dd742552.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script>
    !function(l){function e(e){for(var r,t,n=e[0],o=e[1],u=e[2],f=0,i=[];f<n.length;f++)t=n[f],p[t]&&i.push(p[t][0]),p[t]=0;for(r in o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,r)&&(l[r]=o[r]);for(s&&s(e);i.length;)i.shift()();return c.push.apply(c,u||[]),a()}function a(){for(var e,r=0;r<c.length;r++){for(var t=c[r],n=!0,o=1;o<t.length;o++){var u=t[o];0!==p[u]&&(n=!1)}n&&(c.splice(r--,1),e=f(f.s=t[0]))}return e}var t={},p={2:0},c=[];function f(e){if(t[e])return t[e].exports;var r=t[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return l[e].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,f),r.l=!0,r.exports}f.m=l,f.c=t,f.d=function(e,r,t){f.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},f.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},f.t=function(r,e){if(1&e&&(r=f(r)),8&e)return r;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof r&&r&&r.__esModule)return r;var t=Object.create(null);if(f.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:r}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof r)for(var n in r)f.d(t,n,function(e){return r[e]}.bind(null,n));return t},f.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return f.d(r,"a",r),r},f.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},f.p="/";var r=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],n=r.push.bind(r);r.push=e,r=r.slice();for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)e(r[o]);var s=n;a()}([])
  </script>
  <script src="/static/js/1.a789a71a.chunk.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/js/main.5d390abf.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

One thought, I suppose, is to use an iframe with a specific width/height but that ruins the responsiveness of the app.

Are there any other ways? Thank you very much

Comment: maybe i don't understand but you just have to load your react build and call ReactDOM.render on your root id

Comment: this works only if the React App build is a standalone page.
I can't use `ReactDOM.render` directly as the ES6 scripts throw an error inside the standard websites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you build your App with create-react-app it creates an index.html file that uses your App in that specific index.html file. So for example if you render your app in the `<div id="root"></div>` it will place the app in that div.

If you look at the bottom om the generated index.html file you can see that your React app is just a .js file that is imported at the bottom of the index.html file. The building process bundles everything into this one .js file. The whole React app is in that .js file.

So .. what you can do is take this .js file and import it where you want to use it in your Wordpress site. The one thing you have to remember is that you have to have a DIV that is named exactly the same as the one you mount your React app in. So if you mount it in a div named root like this : `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));` You must have a div named root in the html document you import your build file into. Also make sure you place any subfolders with images etc that you use in your React app in the correct root folder.

Hope this clear things up. =)